# openHAB two Strings to DateTime

Tags: java, xtend, openhab, joda-convert

I have two String variables (one has date and other has time), 
how can I create DateTime from these two String variables ?
The purpose to use PlusMintues PlusDay ...

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, but it failed.

Comment: It is clear, two string variables (one for date as "1/1/2018" and other for time "04:50", and I want to merge to valid DateTime in openHAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried this and it works,

```
val SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" )        
val dateTimeString = dateValue + " " + timeValue
val String dateTimeValue = dateFormatter.format(new Date(dateTimeString))                
val DateTime origStartDate = new DateTime(dateFormatter.parse(dateTimeValue))
```